Linkedin post to mention about my serving notice period
I am currently serving my notice period, with January 20th being my last working day. Unfortunately, LinkedIn does not have a specific option to indicate that I am serving my notice period.
Would it be a good idea to create a LinkedIn post informing my network about this? Is it professional and effective to post such an update? I’d appreciate your advice.

Announcing your resignation publicly in advance may not be well-received by other companies. This notice should only be mentioned to recruiters when interviewing for new positions.
Instead, on your last working days, posting a thank-you note to the company for their support during your tenure will convey your appreciation for your former workplace. This also subtly indicates that you are open to new opportunities, thereby creating a better impression with both your previous and prospective employers.
This is just my opinion. I hope it can be helpful to you!

Please don't answer blatantly off-topic questions.  Doing so will only encourage newbies to do the wrong thing.
